# Reduce memory consumption while loading gif images in UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, memory, uiimageview, gif

I want to show gif image in a UIImageView and with the code below (source: https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/08/load-gif-image-in-swift_22.html, *I did not understand all the codes), I am able to display gif images. However, the memory consumption seems high (tested on real device). Is there any way to modify the code below to reduce the memory consumption?

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url =  "https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*oDqXedYUMyhWzN48pUjHyw.gif"
    let gifImage = UIImage.gifImageWithURL(url)
    imageView.image = gifImage 
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

fileprivate func < <T : Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case let (l?, r?):
        return l < r
    case (nil, _?):
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}

extension UIImage {
   public class func gifImageWithData(_ data: Data) -> UIImage? {
        guard let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data as CFData, nil) else {
            print("image doesn't exist")
            return nil
        }
            return UIImage.animatedImageWithSource(source)
    }

    public class func gifImageWithURL(_ gifUrl:String) -> UIImage? {
        guard let bundleURL:URL? = URL(string: gifUrl) else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: bundleURL!) else {
            return nil
        }
        return gifImageWithData(imageData)
    }

    public class func gifImageWithName(_ name: String) -> UIImage? {
        guard let bundleURL = Bundle.main
        .url(forResource: name, withExtension: "gif") else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: bundleURL) else {
            return nil
        }
        return gifImageWithData(imageData)
    }

    class func delayForImageAtIndex(_ index: Int, source: CGImageSource!) -> Double {
        var delay = 0.1
        let cfProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, index, nil)
        let gifProperties: CFDictionary = unsafeBitCast(
        CFDictionaryGetValue(cfProperties,
                             Unmanaged.passUnretained(kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary).toOpaque()),
        to: CFDictionary.self)

        var delayObject: AnyObject = unsafeBitCast(
        CFDictionaryGetValue(gifProperties,
                             Unmanaged.passUnretained(kCGImagePropertyGIFUnclampedDelayTime).toOpaque()),
        to: AnyObject.self)
        if delayObject.doubleValue == 0 {
            delayObject = unsafeBitCast(CFDictionaryGetValue(gifProperties,
                                                         Unmanaged.passUnretained(kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime).toOpaque()), to: AnyObject.self)
        }

        delay = delayObject as! Double

        if delay < 0.1 {
            delay = 0.1
        }

        return delay
    }

    class func gcdForPair(_ a: Int?, _ b: Int?) -> Int {
        var a = a
        var b = b
        if b == nil || a == nil {
            if b != nil {
                return b!
            } else if a != nil {
                return a!
            } else {
                return 0
            }
        }

        if a < b {
            let c = a
            a = b
            b = c
        }

        var rest: Int
        while true {
            rest = a! % b!

            if rest == 0 {
               return b!
            } else {
                a = b
                b = rest
            }
        }
    }

    class func gcdForArray(_ array: Array<Int>) -> Int {
        if array.isEmpty {
            return 1
        }

        var gcd = array[0]

        for val in array {
            gcd = UIImage.gcdForPair(val, gcd)
        }

       return gcd
    }

    class func animatedImageWithSource(_ source: CGImageSource) -> UIImage? {
        let count = CGImageSourceGetCount(source)
        var images = [CGImage]()
        var delays = [Int]()

        for i in 0..<count {
            if let image = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, i, nil) {
                images.append(image)
            }

            let delaySeconds = UIImage.delayForImageAtIndex(Int(i),
                                                        source: source)
            delays.append(Int(delaySeconds * 1000.0)) // Seconds to ms
        }

        let duration: Int = {
            var sum = 0

            for val: Int in delays {
                sum += val
            }

            return sum
         }()

        let gcd = gcdForArray(delays)
        var frames = [UIImage]()

        var frame: UIImage
        var frameCount: Int
        for i in 0..<count {
            frame = UIImage(cgImage: images[Int(i)])
            frameCount = Int(delays[Int(i)] / gcd)

            for _ in 0..<frameCount {
                frames.append(frame)
            }
        }

        let animation = UIImage.animatedImage(with: frames,
                                          duration: Double(duration) / 1000.0)

        return animation
    }
}
```

[image: tested as gif]

When I render the image as normal png image, the consumption is around 10MB.
[image: tested as non gif]

Comment: how much memory does it use when you comment the gif code

Comment: @sanjaykmwt I have now tested in real device and updated the consumption for both the cases in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The GIF in question has a resolution of 480×288 and contains 10 frames.

Considering that `UIImageView` stores frames as 4-byte RGBA, this GIF occupies 4 × 10 × 480 × 288 = 5 529 600 bytes in RAM, which is more than 5 megabytes.

There are numerous ways to mitigate that, but only one of them puts no additional strain on the CPU; the others are mere CPU-to-RAM trade-offs.

The method I`m talking about is subclassing `UIImageView` and loading your GIFs by hand, preserving their internal representation (indexed image + palette). It would allow you to cut the memory usage fourfold.

N.B.: even though GIFs may be stored as full images for each frame (which is the case for the GIF in question), many are not. On the contrary, most of the frames can only contain the pixels that have changed since the previous one. Thus, in general the internal GIF representation only allows to display frames in direct order.

Other methods of saving RAM include e.g. re-reading every frame from disk prior to displaying it, which is certainly not good for battery life.

Comment: I am now using a library called sdWebImage, which provides gif support. Thanks for the explanation. I would like to try the method you have suggested but i did not get about preserving the internal representation. If you have some code to share, it would be better.

Comment: @Sujal No problem. Consider [this loader](https://github.com/hidefromkgb/gif_load/tree/d62a9de34d20791fd004241f506adb8aaa1bfbd0). You can build it using any ObjC/C++ compiler you like. The `GIF_WHDR` structure passed to a caller-defined frame callback contains pretty much the complete internal representation, just in a more convenient form than in a raw GIF. If you only store unique palettes and the partial index images, you save plenty of RAM. The (minor) downside is that you need to construct the resulting image yourself, but that boils down to replicating the example code above.

Answer (score -1):

To display GIFs with less memory consumption, try [BBWebImage](https://github.com/Silence-GitHub/BBWebImage).

BBWebImage will decide how many image frames are decoded and cached depending on current memory usage. If free memory is not enough, only part of image frames are decoded and cached.

For Swift 4:

```swift
// BBAnimatedImageView (subclass UIImageView) displays animated image
imageView = BBAnimatedImageView(frame: frame)

// Load and display gif
imageView.bb_setImage(with: url,
                      placeholder: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))
{ (image: UIImage?, data: Data?, error: Error?, cacheType: BBImageCacheType) in
    // Do something when finish loading
}
```